# what may be the root cause of QueryParameterException in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, remoteexception

yesterday i have run my application and it was throwing the below error.

```
[7/2/14 3:39:37:228 CDT] 0000002e SystemErr     R Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
            java.rmi.RemoteException: 
            >> SERVER (id=4773e3aa, host=was01) TRACE START:
            >>    java.rmi.RemoteException: ; nested exception is: 
            org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [payeeName]
```

am checked the query and it is correct.

```
select count(distinct fci.commonEntitySK || fci.lobCode || adi.alternateID || fci.payeeCommonEntityTypeCode || adi.typeCode || fi.sortName ) FROM FCI fci, P p, AI ai, FI fi WHERE fci.commonEntitySK = p.commonEntity.commonEntitySK (+) AND fci.commonEntitySK = fi.commonEntitySK(+) AND ai.p.sysID(+) = p.sysID AND lower(fi.sortName) LIKE :payeeName

Query query = getSession().createQuery(finalQuery.toString());
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(payeeName))
        {
            query.setParameter("payeeName", payeeName);
        }
```

But after that, today i checked and am not getting any exception...

Please give some clue to find out the root cause of this exception...

Comment: Please show you statement.

Comment: With just the error stack trace, there is little help we can offer. You need to show the query and the entity class being used in it.

Comment: Could post the query which contains the parameter payeeName and the entity class it comes from please.

Comment: Could you post the annotations for each entity class?